# Automapper pivoting list

Tags: c#, automapper

How do you pivot lists in Automapper ? 
e.g. I've a list :

```
var cust = new CustomerDTO {
    Name = "Cust 1",
    CrossRefList = new List<CrossRefDTO> { 
        new CrossRefDTO{ id="A", ref="123"},
        new CrossRefDTO{ id="B", ref="456"},
        new CrossRefDTO{ id="C", ref="789"},
    } 
}
```

How can I map it like so :

```
CustomerVM
{
    Name = "Cust 1",
    refA = "123",
    refB = "456",
    refC = "789"
}
```

i.e. from a list of objects to single object with a lot of properties.

I know I could do it like so :

```
.ForMember(d => d.refA, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Single(id == "A").id))
```

But not only this doesn't work if there is no reference of id A in the source list, where ideally I would want refA to be null; but I also need to go the other way around i.e. from the object to the list.

Is there anyway to achieve that with Automapper ?

Comment: If you use `SingleOrDefault` then it will work without a reference and set the value to null. For the reverse mapping you will probably have to use a TypeConverter to manage the conversion.

Comment: Derp, of course SingleOrDefault would work, sorry I spent so long working on a other thing related to AutoMapper I forgot how to Linq, still this solution is a bit 'dirty' if you have are more than one property to map

Comment: What is the output type? Or is it a dictionary?

Comment: It's a simple object, gimme a sec to rewrite the example with C# instead of pseudo-code

Comment: Here is this clearer ?

Comment: Yes it is. Can you please explain again what is the problem with the `SingleOrDefault` approach? How many properties do you have to map?

Comment: My biggest concern is that I have to repeat the filter for every property I want to map from the row object, CrossRefDTO in the example, it's not a huge problem, but I was hopping there would be an other option, being pretty new at Automapper I thought I might have missed something.